# How do I get my scikit-learn library to work on windows using pip package installer?

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I am using the windows command prompt to install the scikit learn library using the command pip install -U scikit-learn. However, whenever I try to import it into my program I get an error stating that there is no module named 'sklearn'. Also, whenever I download the library using pip, for some reason, my pip package installer seems to break and pip is no longer recognized as a command on my cmd.  I have numerous other modules which work perfectly fine so I don't see a reason as to why I can't get this specific library to work. I am still quite new to this kind of thing, so maybe I am missing something.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
```

File "<pyshell#0>", line 1, in 
import sklearn
File "C:\Users\Ryan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\sklearn_*init*_.py", line 82, in 
from .base import clone
File "C:\Users\Ryan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\sklearn\base.py", line 17, in 
from .utils import *IS_32BIT
File "C:\Users\Ryan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils_*init**.py", line 20, in 
from scipy.sparse import issparse
File "C:\Users\Ryan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\scipy\sparse_*init*_.py", line 227, in 
from .base import *
File "C:\Users\Ryan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\scipy\sparse\base.py", line 4, in 
from .sputils import (isdense, isscalarlike, isintlike,
File "C:\Users\Ryan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\scipy\sparse\sputils.py", line 8, in 
from scipy._lib._util import prod
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'scipy._lib._util'

Comment: Do you use Anaconda?

Comment: No I do not. Will I be able to get it to work with my visual studio code, which is the IDE I use?

Comment: You should include the exact pip command you've run when you mention "try to download the library using pip" and the error messages you've got. Are you running something different from `pip install -U scikit-learn`?
Also, it is probably worth trying running `import sklearn` in a python terminal before doing it on an IDE. Sometimes the IDE is not accessing the right environment.

Comment: I receive no error messages during pip installation process. The module is simply 'not recognized' whenever i try to import it into my program on VSCode. However, a couple minutes after the installation, For some reason whenever i try to run any pip command later, i receive a '' 'pip' is not recognized as an internal or external command" message and have to reinstall python again on my system each time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to upgrade pip to newest version by `python -m pip install --upgrade pip` considering you are still using Windows. And then try to download sciKitLearn by `pip install sklearn`
This is how I had solved my problem but keep note that it was about a year ago

If all this doesn't work, try VirtualEnv.

Comment: I just did this and the installation seems to have taken place, even though an error popped up on my command prompt stating 'Failed building wheel for sklearn'. I tried to import sklearn into my program and now I am getting a 'No module named 'scipy._lib._util'' error in my terminal. (I am using VSCode) Any idea why that is?

Comment: Try uninstalling whatever you installed by using "pip unistall <library_name>" and re-install. Also regarding your not able to import problem are you running WSL or any other thing that may cause VS Code to use another terminal? Also try importing the module in the IDLE or Shell first rather than in the IDE to see where the problem lies as in system or in the IDE

Comment: I tried importing the library in python IDLE i am getting a long list of errors pointing at various files in my site-packages folder. Should i paste it in here? and if so where do i do this, it is my first time using stackoverflow. I'm also not using any other terminals such as WSL.

Comment: First of all Sorry on confusing you with the WSL stuff. And yes please paste the error here, i may be able to help you. I am fairly new to StackOverFlow too. you can't paste code in comments as far as i know but you can create a new question in which you can ask why it is not installing properly and paste the error in he code block given when you write the question. And pls send a link to that question here. Thanks

Comment: No problem. I have edited the question to include the error message.

Comment: I recommend you install the dependencies of SciKitLearn that are NumPy, SciPy. So try "pip install <packages mentioned one by one>" and then try "pip install scikit-learn"

Comment: I already have numpy installed, and when i install scipy, it says 'requirement already satisfied', so i'm assuming I already have it installed aswell.

Comment: I am sorry. I am going to recommend that you start looking into virtualenv. It is very easy to get used to and to install. It creates a virtual environment for you to install your libraries and run your code. It comes with set-up tools pre-configured and you should not see these type of errors there.

Comment: Professional Devs use Virtual Environments all the time. Also my experience with it has been fantastic

Comment: Thank you so much for the advice! I set up my virtual environment and it had finally worked. You saved me a lot of time and frustration and I appreciate the time you took to respond to my question.